# Multiple Unnamed Nested Classes

Tags: c++, scope, inner-classes, anonymous-class, unnamed-class

```
class grphD::App
{
    ...

    protected:
        class 
        {
            ...
        } console_handler;

        class
        {
            ...
        } grid;
};
```

How can I access App::console_handler inside App::grid functions without having console_handler static and keeping console_handler an object of an anonymous class?

Comment: Not standard C++ - `warning: anonymous structs are a GNU extension [-Wgnu-anonymous-struct] `

Comment: So it's better to name the class also if I'm gonna use it only once?

Comment: Does `grid` know anything at all about (i.e., have access to) the `App` object it is a member of?

Comment: `decltype(console_handler)` might help.  But giving it a type name would probably be better.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm grid is a member of App

Comment: But `grid` is a class object that has no knowledge of or access to the parent class, so it can't access anything in `App`. Did you add something to give it that access?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I didn't. I thought it would've automatically gained access to App members, maybe prefixing them with App::

Comment: Btw, if anonymous classes are not part of standard C++ I think I'll just give them a name.